# Post of Gratitude

Tags: discussion

Knowing the frequency and quantity of my questions, I thought to communicate my continued thanks for everyone who has aided and educated me, and for this SE's kind, welcoming attitude (that other SE sites do not appear to sustain). Please do advise me here if I can ameliorate my approach or learning or questions here in general.

I also wish to emphasise my creed to contribute and to return the aid which I have tried to achieve not by answering substantively as I am still inexperienced, but by ameliorating the writing (syntax and semantics) of all content.